# dish customization in food ordering

Tags: database

I wanted to make sure the design for a particular part is correct or not.
The scenario is:

A pizza can be customized by its size, toppings, crust etc. but the prize of toppings will depend on the size; like when size `7"` is selected the prize for each topping will be `$1` and for size `14"` the prize will be `$2` (or some other customization can be dependent on some other one).

One of the customization can be available only for a particular size; like when size `7"` is selected then only another customization will be displayed.
(This scenario is just an example and there are many more things other than pizza which will have customization as it is a food ordering app )

Currently for this problem I've designed 3 tables:

1. `Dishes(d_id,name,desc,base_price)`
2. `Customization(c_id,d_id(foreign key,name)`
3. `options(o_id,c_id(foreign key),parent_id,name,price)`

The customization table will hold the name of customization like size, crust, toppings etc.
And the options table will hold the contents of each customization.
The `parent_id` in options will refer the options table because toppings price will be dependent on the size selected options.

eg:

```
1) dishes
id name 
1 pizza
2) customization
c_id d_id name
1 1 size
2 1 toppings
3) options
o_id c_id parent_id name price
1 1 1 7" 5$
2 1 2 14" 10$
3 2 1 abc 1$
4 2 2 abc 2$
```

Is there any better way of representing this in the db.
Please guys revert back as soon as possible and please suggest any other changes or functionality I should include in the design(other than this part too).
It will be great if any helpful links are provided.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is parent_id in options table is the foreign key of d_id in dishes table?

Comment: No.Parent_id will refer to the options table.

Comment: Let me know, if I'm wrong..... for each dish, the options price may vary... so there should be relation among dishes and options...

Comment: No. For each dish there can be many customization and for each customization there can be many options.

Comment: Dish and customization are related and customization and options are related